# How to get arithmetical operators at runtime?

Tags: java, arithmetic-expressions

How I can get arithmetical operators at run-time in Java? Suppose if I have values

- `ADD` it should add the number
- `MUL` then it should multiply the number

For Example

```
  public calculate(int x, String str){
   while(str.equals("some value")){
     If( str.equals("ADD"))
        // it should return me something like x+
     if( str.equals("MUL"))
        it return me something like x*
    }
    if( str.equals("FINAL"))
        it should return me x+x*x

  }
```

Comment: I voted to close as IMO it is far too localized.

Comment: I do not understand your problem, you already provided the solution in pseudo code. Just do `return x * x;` and change your method signature to `public int calculate(...)`.

Comment: Hi Home I modified my question..

Comment: I still do not understand it. What *exactly* do you mean by 'something like x*'? What's the problem with the 2 answers provided below?

Comment: I don't see any reason why this question is being closed. Stackoverflow users, please do not abuse your reputation points and your rights.

Comment: @OP, the purpose of the `while` loop and the `"FINAL"` case in your example is not clear.

Comment: Use the `ScriptEngine` - no messing about with parsing strings (in your code), just pass the entire equation to ECMA script to evaluate.

Comment: OP is trying to write a simple compiler (from what I can tell). Why are you trying to write the above code? Either you are solving a simpler problem in a difficult way or your interests are getting you a bit ahead of yourself.

Comment: Voting to close as meaningless. If you want to add, add. There is no real question in evidence here.

Comment: @EJP, surely you can see my answer, and OP's comment below it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is not runtime metaprogramming, but first class functions.

The following represent first class functions, with arity 1 and 2 respectively.

```
abstract class UnaryFunction<A, B> {
  public abstract B apply(A a);
}

abstract class BinaryFunction<A, B, C> {
  public abstract C apply(A a, B b);
}
```

For the sake of simplicity, let's use specialized versions of above classes.

```
abstract class UnaryOperation {
  public abstract int apply(int a);
}

abstract class BinaryOperation {
  public abstract int apply(int a, int b);
}
```

Now construct a dictionary of the required arithmetic operations.

```
Map<String, BinaryOperation> ops = new HashMap<String, BinaryOperation>();
ops.put("ADD", new BinaryOperation() {
  public int apply(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
  }
});
ops.put("MUL", new BinaryOperation() {
  public int apply(int a, int b) {
    return a * b;
  }
});
// etc.
```

Add a method that partially applies `BinaryOperation` on one parameter.

```
abstract class BinaryOperation {
  public abstract int apply(int a, int b);

  public UnaryOperation partial(final int a) {
    return new UnaryOperation() {
      public int apply(int b) {
        return BinaryOperation.this.apply(a, b);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Now we can write your `calculate` method.

```
public UnaryOperation calculate(int x, String opString) {
  BinaryOperation op = ops.get(opString);
  if(op == null)
    throw new RuntimeException("Operation not found.");
  else
    return op.partial(x);
}
```

Use:

```
UnaryOperation f = calculate(3, "ADD");
f.apply(5); // returns 8

UnaryOperation g = calculate(9, "MUL");
f.apply(11); // returns 99
```

The abstractions used in the above solution, namely first class function interfaces and partial application, are both available in [this](http://functionaljava.org/) library.

Comment: After checking [the edit history of the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10859834/revisions), I think I might have completely missed the point of the question. OP needs to put in more effort to explain his case.

Comment: Thanks a lot missingfaktor thats what I need :)

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Calculator {
    public static enum Operation {ADD, MUL, SUB, DIV};
    private int x; // store value from previous operations

    public void calculate(int x, Operation operation) {
        switch(operation) {
        case ADD:
            this.x += x;
            break;
        case MUL:
            this.x *= x;
            break;
        case SUB:
            this.x -= x;
            break;
        case DIV:
            this.x /= x;
            break;
        }
    }

    public int getResult() {
        return this.x;
    }
}
```

To use it elsewhere in your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calculator c = new Calculator();
    c.calculate(4, Calculator.Operation.ADD);
    // Other operations
    c.getResult(); // get final result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to just add and multiply `x`, just do the following:

```
public int calculate(int x, String str) {
    // while(true) is gonna get you into some trouble
    if( str.equals("ADD")) {
        return x + x;
    }
    else if( str.equals("MUL")) {
        return x * x;
    }
    else
        return x; // not sure what you want to do in this case
}
```

Comment: Hi TreeBranch, Thanks for your response I modified my question I think there was some confusion